# How to derive the canonical momentum of a single spin in the magnetic field in classical mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, condensed-matter, hamiltonian-formalism, topological-field-theory

The classical spin can be denoted as $\vec{S}=S\, \vec{n}$, where $\vec{n}=(\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi},\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi},\cos{\theta})$. The magnet field $\vec{h}=(0,0,h)$.

The Hamiltonian is $H=-hS\cos{\theta}$. The classical equation of motion is just the $\partial_{t}\vec{n}=\vec{n}\times \vec{h}$, decompose into the components, we find $$\dot{\phi}=-h,\\ \dot{\theta}=0.$$

The Hamilton's equations can be written as $$\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_{\phi}}=\dot{\phi}=-h,\\\frac{\partial H}{\partial \phi}=-\dot{p}_{\phi}=0,$$ and
$$\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial p_{\theta}}=\dot{\theta}=0,\\\frac{\partial H}{\partial\theta}=-\dot{p}_{\theta}=hS\sin{\theta}.$$

From the first Hamilton's equation, we know the canonical momentum $p_{\phi}$ can be written as $$p_{\phi}=S\cos{\theta}+C,$$ $C$ is some constant. The corresponding Lagrangian is $$L=p_{\phi}\dot{\phi}-H=(S\cos{\theta}+C)\dot{\phi}+hS\cos{\theta}.$$ The Euler-Lagrangian equations give
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}-\partial_{t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}}=0\,\to \sin{\theta}\dot{\theta}=0,\\\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}-\partial_{t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}=0\,\to \sin{\theta}(\dot{\phi}+h)=0.$$ They just give the same equation of motion above.

**My question is how to determine the constant $C$ in canonical momentum $p_{\phi}$ ?**

According to Abanov [arXiv:1708.07192](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.07192), $p_{\phi}=-S(1-\cos{\theta})$, then the first term in Lagrangian gives the Wess-Zumino-Witten term in the action $$-4\pi S\frac{1}{4\pi}\int dt(1-\cos{\theta})\dot{\phi}=-4\pi S\frac{1}{4\pi}\int d\phi(1-\cos{\theta})=-4\pi S \frac{\Omega}{4\pi}.$$